# The flexbox container isn't horizontal scrollable and the items doesn't match screen with

Tags: html, flexbox

The idea was making a simple one page website.
But for the 'projects section' in need the 'slides' divs past each other,
and a simple horizontal scrollbar to view them.. or maybe later soms buttons.

Flexbox should fix it..right? only the width of the slides doesn't fit the screen(vw)..
they are smaller.. like they change on the size of 'section2' width.. and the scrollbar stays locked. i'm stuck.. and checked different places but still the same problem.
Or is there a better way to fix this then using flexbox?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">Page 1</div>
    <div class="section">Page 2</div>
    <div class="section">Page 3</div>
    <div class="section">
        <--- these pages has to be screen width and the horizontal scrollbar has to work--->
        <div class="section2"> 
            <div class="slide">Projects Section</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 1</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 2</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 3</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 4</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 5</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 6</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 7</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 8</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 9</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Page 5</div>
    <div class="section">Page 6</div>
    <div class="section">Page 7</div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; max-width: calc(100vw - 15px);
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(204, 85, 85);
    border-right: 5px solid rgb(174, 26, 26);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden ;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.section2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    position:relative;
    width: 10000px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(204, 85, 85);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: scroll ;
    overflow-y: hidden ;
}

.slide {
    flex :1;
    float:left;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    width: 100vw ;
    height:90vh;
    background-color: rgb(90, 123, 135);
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
/****************************************************************
* Scrollbar
****************************************************************/

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 10px;
scrollbar-color: #9aa0a6 transparent;
scrollbar-width: thin;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: #f1f1f1; 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background: #555; 
}
```

and made already the resize js script..

```js
 window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var windowWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
    var slidesWidth = document.getElementsByClassName(".slide")
    slidesWidth.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
});
```

but it doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp)
and
[codepen](https://codepen.io/ygorperez/pen/LYOvqQy)
here

Add

```
.section2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Remove all flexbox properties and section 2 width

You probably don't need a lot of things that are in there like the JavaScript.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; max-width: calc(100vw - 15px);
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(204, 85, 85);
    border-right: 5px solid rgb(174, 26, 26);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden ;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.section2 {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(204, 85, 85);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: scroll ;
    overflow-y: hidden ;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    width: 100vw ;
    height:90vh;
    background-color: rgb(90, 123, 135);
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
/****************************************************************
* Scrollbar
****************************************************************/

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 10px;
scrollbar-color: #9aa0a6 transparent;
scrollbar-width: thin;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: #f1f1f1; 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">Page 1</div>
    <div class="section">Page 2</div>
    <div class="section">Page 3</div>
    <div class="section">
        <--- these pages has to be screen width and the horizontal scrollbar has to work--->
        <div class="section2"> 
            <div class="slide">Projects Section</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 1</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 2</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 3</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 4</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 5</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 6</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 7</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 8</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 9</div>
            <div class="slide">subpage 10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Page 5</div>
    <div class="section">Page 6</div>
    <div class="section">Page 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works!
also didn't need section2 anymore :)